# Devise customization

Tags: devise, ruby-on-rails-3.2, administration

I want to configure the devise gem for admin user. In my application ive installed the devise gem and currently it is used as a normal user who has account in my application. I want to add administration in my application so that an admin user can delete or modify etc operations to a particular user account and also do other administrative work such as deleting the user data which is not appropriate for public users.

Answer (score 1):

I'd look into two gems: [RailsAdmin](https://github.com/sferik/rails_admin) and [CanCan](https://github.com/ryanb/cancan).

Comment: what about phpmyadmin? Actually i am new in ROR so will you please explain me this that till now i haven't created admin thing in my application. It is just an application over which many account holder users will maintain their catalogue. So what are my next steps in creating admin user and what operations it should perform?

Comment: I would recommend going through the Ruby on Rails Tutorial (http://ruby.railstutorial.org/) so you're more familiar with Rails. It's hard to talk about what you want to do with your current level of experience.